# @Grid With Channel Form single form template Multiple Time on same page Grid not working

Tags: safecracker, grid

WE have Integrated Channel form with Grid on Front End.

That channel form Template load by ajax on page multiple at a same time update.

e.g one channe form edit two time on same page load by ajax then first load form grid working fine when second form open for edit at same time when first one already open then second open form grid field not working.

let me know any idea for this.

Thanks,
PD

UPDATE:

Here is My Code When We have added single form multiple time in one page that time only first one add row of grid functionality working but other form not working.

My Code this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
{exp:channel:form channel="test_form" id="test1"  return="channel-form/index" json="no" include_jquery="no" include_assets="yes"}
   <input name="title" type="text">

    {field:test_entry}

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}

{exp:channel:form channel="test_form" id="test2"  return="channel-form/index" json="no" include_jquery="no" include_assets="yes"}
   <input name="title" type="text">

    {field:test_entry}

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}
</body>
</htm>
```

Above My Code for two channel form in multiple time use in single page but add row of grid not working of second one.

Comment: Please include the relevant template code and javascript in your question, along with any javascript console errors you might be receiving.